# Problem using ExternalCodeComp in Openmdao

Tags: openmdao

I am trying out the example problem for ExternalCodeComp as given in openmdao [docs](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/external_code_comp.html).

The optimization code is

```python
import openmdao.api as om
from openmdao.components.tests.test_external_code_comp import ParaboloidExternalCodeCompFD

prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

model.add_subsystem('p', ParaboloidExternalCodeCompFD(), promotes_inputs=['x', 'y'])

# find optimal solution with SciPy optimize
# solution (minimum): x = 6.6667; y = -7.3333
prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('p.x', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_design_var('p.y', lower=-50, upper=50)

prob.model.add_objective('p.f_xy')

prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True

prob.setup()

# Set input values
prob.set_val('p.x', 3.0)
prob.set_val('p.y', -4.0)

prob.run_driver()
print(prob.get_val('p.x'))
print(prob.get_val('p.y'))
```

However, I get the following error at `prob.setup()`.

```python
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Group (<model>): Output not found for design variable 'p.x'.
```

What does this mean ? I dont know if I am missing something basic. The problem only occurs when I try to optimize it. There is no problem when I just use the external code in a model (as given in the docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you promoted the inputs `x` and `y`

```
model.add_subsystem('p', ParaboloidExternalCodeCompFD(), promotes_inputs=['x', 'y'])
```

Notice that you did not promote the output `f_xy`

so from the top level of the model the correct paths are:
`p.f_xy` for the output, but `x` and `y` for the inputs.

Thus the correct way to add the design variables and set the values was to use `x` and `y`.

```
import openmdao.api as om
from openmdao.components.tests.test_external_code_comp import ParaboloidExternalCodeCompFD

prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

model.add_subsystem('p', ParaboloidExternalCodeCompFD(), promotes_inputs=['x', 'y'])

# find optimal solution with SciPy optimize
# solution (minimum): x = 6.6667; y = -7.3333
prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('x', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_design_var('y', lower=-50, upper=50)

prob.model.add_objective('p.f_xy')

prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True

prob.setup()

# Set input values
prob.set_val('x', 3.0)
prob.set_val('y', -4.0)

prob.run_driver()
print(prob.get_val('x'))
print(prob.get_val('y'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I still get a similar error though. `Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Group (<model>): Output not found for design variable 'x'.`

Comment: Ok. Neither your suggested changes nor the code in the docs work. But it works when i remove `promotes_input` from my code and connect the variables with ivc. Thank you for helping me see the issue.

Comment: im not sure why the code didn't work for you. When I ran the above code, I got the expected output.